# Image compression not working as intended

Tags: c#, aforge

Here is some code that I put together (I didn't write all of this)

```
Bitmap thisScreenshot = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(thisScreenshot);
IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxScreenshot.GetHdc();
PrintWindow(WindowToFind, hdcBitmap, 0);
gfxScreenshot.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
//until this is part its just getting image of window(thisScreenshot)
AForge.Imaging.Filters.ResizeBilinear filter = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.ResizeBilinear(100, 60);
Bitmap forthumbnail = filter.Apply(thisScreenshot);
pictureBox1.Image = forthumbnail;
//created thumbnail


//this is where it gets slightly interesting:
Choppa = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.Crop(new Rectangle(150,55,250,200));
Bitmap croppedACCEPTtext = Choppa.Apply(thisScreenshot);
string img1_ref, img2_ref;
Bitmap img1 = croppedACCEPTtext;
Bitmap img2 = Properties.Resources.txt305;
int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
bool flag = true;
if (img1.Width == img2.Width && img1.Height == img2.Height)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < img1.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img1.Height; j++)
        {
            img1_ref = img1.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
            img2_ref = img2.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
            if (img1_ref != img2_ref)
            {
                count2++;
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
            count1++;
        }
    }

    if (count2 < 200)
    {
        //THIS IS WORKS, AND HAPPENS CORRECTLY.
        //THIS IS WORKS, AND HAPPENS CORRECTLY.
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
else
{

}
//Now, remaining part above doesnt work. 
//its always false, unless when I look for count2 <400, then its always true.
AForge.Imaging.Filters.Crop Choppah = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.Crop(new Rectangle(150, 55, 350, 300));
croppedACCEPTtext = Choppah.Apply(thisScreenshot);
img1 = croppedACCEPTtext;
count1 = 0;
count2 = 0;
flag = true;
img2 = Properties.Resources.txt306;
if (img1.Width == img2.Width && img1.Height == img2.Height)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < img1.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img1.Height; j++)
        {
            img1_ref = img1.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
            img2_ref = img2.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
            if (img1_ref != img2_ref)
            {
                count2++;
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
            count1++;
        }
    }

    if (count2 < 400)
    {
        //fail ?
    }
    else

    {
    }
}
else
{

}
```

This code isn't mine, and they fail for some reason.  I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: What does "they fail for some reason" mean? What you have posted won't compile. Do you get an error? What error? You are calling `GetPixel` on images you haven't shown us; how could we possibly know what `count2` is or how it "fails"?

Answer (score 2):

You should describe what you mean by fail.

If I follow it correctly, the first section makes:

1. img1 a cropped version of the window screenshot
2. img2 is a random bitmap called .txt305

Then we compare the Colors between identical points and increment a counter if they are the same. According to you, it succeeds when no more than 199 of the pixels match color.

(or rather no more than 199 **columns** of the images have a matching color, since the break statement doesn't jump out of both for loops.)

The second section makes:

1. img1 is a slightly larger cropped version of the window screenshot
2. img2 is a random bitmap called .txt306

The colors are compared (assuming the image sizes are the same) at identical points, and a counter is incremented if they are the same.

According to you, this fails because less than 399 of the columns of img1 contains a matching pixel color to img2.

What behavior do you expect? (How many columns do you expect would have positionally equivalent pixels with the same color?)

My assumption is that the second part will always have count2 < 400, since it was made by counting the number of columns of the images that have at least 1 matching pixel.  But you made 1 of those images by cropping, and the cropping done with:

```
new Rectangle(150, 55, 350, 300)
```

makes it seem like the new img2 doesn't have more than 400 columns.

Perhaps you intended to use the "continue" keyword instead of "break"